# Custom Certificate Validation in Worklight Hybrid Apps

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I am trying to do some custom certificate validation in Worklight apps. That mean I want to validate the server certificate of some perticular website against some cutom certificates which I have.

So is there any support in WL for custom certificate validation during https connection?

If such support is not there and I have to do it on my own way, which certificate format I can use in my device against which the server certificates can be validated? Does the certificate format independent of WL and purely dependent on the platform we are using like android and iOS?

Note: I am developing the WL hybrid app for Android and iOS devices. So I am expecting answers for both platform, if its different for both platform.

Answer (score 0):

Closest that I can think of is Certificate Pinning in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1.

You can read more about this support in the following user documentation topic: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_cert_pinning_intro.html?lang=en

Comment: Hi Idan, Thanks for the response. I went through the documentations. I have few queries. 1. Does this cert pinning feature of WL will also be applied to URL cert pinning. i.e. if i want to pin one certificate for a particular URL, so that only if my cert matched with the server certificate from the url, then it should proceed.  2. In case it applies to URL cert pinning, and since only one cert can be pinned at a time, does it mean we will be able to access only one url at a time. To access a new url everytime, do we need to call the method pinTrustedCertificatePublicKey with new certificate?

Comment: The pinning applies only to a specific URL which should be that of the MFP server. The pinning API should  be called only once in the app lifecycle - but before any request to the URL (the server) is made.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. But I guess the API will not serve my purpose.
I have the below requirement.
1. I wish to pin cert for facebook.com
2. So when facebook.com will be pinged from the WL app, it should get the certificate from facebook.com server and first validate with the pinned cert (i.e. whatever certificate I have pinned for facebook.com)
3. If validated it should proceed else it should reject.

Is there any other way in WL to achieve the above purpose?